# PHP: How to get last execution time of a specific file?

Tags: php, wordpress

In php how to get last execution time of a specific file?
I am working on a plugin which is a cron job and I want its last execution time.
how can i get it?
Actually problem is suppose due to some problem my is not executed then how can I know what was it's last execution time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best option would be too use a database (a flat file database like a simple text file would be fine) and store the time so you can read it later.

But if thats not an option try using the fileatime(). It should work fine as long as your cron job is the only one accessing the file in question

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fileatime.php

Comment: ohh thanks its awesome. First one ( that is creating a table in database ) was my last option, but you gave me a good new option thanks a lot for that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can log it somewhere. Otherwise that information isn't available.

Use [`microtime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) to get an accurate time measure.

Comment: yes you are right ad thanks for your help. But I don't know that how to create log and log file and where it should store?
Can you please explain?